# Сравнение двух текстовых файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно составить программу в python 3.0. Программа должна сравнивать исходный файл с текстом с другим текстовым файлом. Нужно разбить текст на строки, если больше 50 повторяю.

Comment: Александра вопрос в чём заключается ?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще сравнить 2 файла можно так:

```
In [2]: open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DKOM-Rootkit-master\numbers.txt').read() == open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DKOM-Rootkit-master\text.txt').read()
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_different_files(file1, file2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:  # открыть файлы на чтение
        for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):  # читать построчно оба файла
            if not line1 == line2:  # сравниваем строки
                return True  # разные

if is_different_files('test1.log', 'test2.log'):
    print('файлы разные')
```

Comment: Если строк не равное кол-во?